# A poem that works in both Latin and Italian

Tags: poetry, passage-identification, italian

Years ago an old colleague showed me a poem which had a miraculous feature:
it was perfectly valid Latin and perfectly valid Italian.
With clever choices of words one can make that happen, but it also happened to convey a message or tell a story.
My recollection is that the theme was Christianity.

Does this ring a bell to someone?
I would be glad if someone could either identify this or provide another text with the same bilingual property.
I understand that the level of detail might be insufficient to find the exact poem (and I may or may not recognize it), but the phenomenon should be unambiguous enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This page](http://www.fmboschetto.it/religione/Salve_Regina.htm) (in Italian) has three bilingual Italian-Latin poems.

"[Salve Regina](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salve_Regina_(Anacleto_Bendazzi))" by [Anacleto Bendazzi](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacleto_Bendazzi) (1883-1982) seems to be the Christian-themed one (though I don't know either Italian or Latin well enough to translate it myself):

> Salve Regina ! Te saluto, o pia,
>   nostra tutela in tenebrosa via,
>   in sinistra terrifica procella
>   benigna stella.
>
> Quando te non saluto, o nostra vita,
>   gemo in amaritudine infinita;
>   in tranquilla quiete, te invocata,
>   vivo, o beata.
>
> Saluto te, Regina gloriosa,
>   arca divina, intemerata rosa;
>   te, bella oliva, Iris serena, pura,
>   nivea figura.
>
> Quando miser vacillo in vento infido,
>   Regina generosa, in te confido;
>   in te confido in fausta, in dura sorte,
>   in vita, in morte.

Translation:

> Hail Queen! I salute thee, o loving,
>   our safeguard in a dark path,
>   in a menacing and terrifying storm,
>   benevolent star.
>
> When I do not salute thee, our life,
>   I suffer in infinite bitterness;
>   having invoked thee, 
>   I live in peaceful serenity,
>   o blessed.
>
> I salute thee, glorious Queen,
>   divine ark, faultless rose;
>   thee, beautiful olive, serene Iris, 
>   pure, snow-white figure.
>
> When I, miserable, waver in treacherous wind,
>   generous Queen, in thee I trust;
>   in thee I trust in auspicious, in ominous fate,
>   in life, in death.

The two other poems on the page are one by [Gabriello Chiabrera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriello_Chiabrera) (1552-1638) and "Elogio a Venezia" by Mattia Butturini (1752-1817). In prose there are also the sentences [I vitelli dei romani sono belli](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_vitelli_dei_romani_sono_belli) and [Cane Nero magna bella Persica](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cane_Nero_magna_bella_Persica) (in Italian (Roman dialect for the latter), respectively, *The calves of the Romans are beautiful* and *Black dog eats nice peach*).

Comment: +1! I added the translations, feel free to rollback or change some wording for the English version of the poem.